# AutoCompleteTextView getText() в событии onItemClick

Tags: android, android-sdk

В событии `onItemClick` для `AutoCompleteTextView` необходимо получить текст самого `AutoCompleteTextView`.
У меня это не получается, `AutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString()` возвращает какую-то ерунду:

```
AutoCompleteTextView mEditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

mEditText.setAdapter(new MyAdapterCompleteItem()); // adapter with CompleteItems

mEditText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

   CompleteItem myitem = (CompleteItem) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
   String str = mEditText.getText().toString();
    // здесь str == ‘com.my.CompleteItem@52851578'
 }
}
});
```